# Bootstrap3-DateTimePicker-Rails with odd behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the Bootstrap3-DateTimePicker-Rails by TrevorS.  Everything works ok with the calendar on my textbox, however, when I switched my form into a table so there are two cells per row, the DateTimePicker pops up on the wrong textbox (the left most textbox).  Using the WidgetPosition(), I can get it to appear closer to the correct text box, but it is still trying to link to the left most textbox.  I have verified numerous times that it is binding to the correct textbox.  I am not sure why this behavior is occurring. I would appreciate any help or insight!

```
<%= form_for @course, :url => url_for(controller: 'completed_courses', action: 'create')  do |f| %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= f.label :course_name, "Course Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :course_name, class: 'form-control' %>              
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= f.label :start_date, "Start Date" %>
      <%= f.text_field :start_date, class: 'form-control', :value => Date.today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>  
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= f.label :sponser, "Course Sponser" %>
      <%= f.text_field :sponser, class: 'form-control' %>  
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= f.label :end_date, "End Date" %>
      <%= f.text_field :end_date, class: 'form-control', :value => Date.today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>  
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function () {

    $('#completed_course_start_date').datetimepicker({ 
      format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
      widgetPositioning: {
        vertical: 'auto',
        horizontal: 'right'
      }
    });

    $('#completed_course_end_date').datetimepicker({ 
      format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
      widgetPositioning: {
        vertical: 'auto',
        horizontal: 'right'
      }
    });   

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The datetimepicker component should be nested within a relative positioned container, which is likely the cause of any alignment issues. I would remove any of the attempts at `widgetPositioning`, and recommend using bootstrap's default `input-group` container, or another relative positioned container of your choosing.

```
<div class="input-group date" id="completed_course_start_date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
```

You can see the behavior in action here http://jsfiddle.net/spasticdonkey/otsq3ouj/3/

Notice the left input has issues displaying the picker.